# how to sort vector of items in android while targeting api level 15?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to sort vector of items using comparator in android.
I tried:

```
vector.sort(new myComparator());
```

but it shows error:

```
Call requires API level 24 (current min is 15): java.util.Vector#sort
```

Any solution to it??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`Collections.sort()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List%3CT%3E,%20java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20T%3E)) -

```
Collections.sort(vector, new myComparator());
```

Also think about using `ArrayList<>` instead of `Vector` - `Vector` is deprecated

Comment: Glad to hear it - please upvote/accept my answer so that anyone else searching for a similar problem knows this solution worked.

Comment: done already! but my reputation is less than 15, it will not be reflected.